# DateTime.Now/UtcNow Default Culture - Client or Server?

Tags: c#, datetime, culture

I know how to specify cultures, date formats, time zones, etc...

My question here is when you just type DateTime.Now or DateTime.UtcNow in C#, is it using the culture from the web server your server-side code runs on, or is it using the client-side lang/culture of the web browser making the request?

To my great surprise, from my testing, it looks like this server code DateTime.Now is not using the web server's culture.  But is actually using the client Lang/Cult inside the web browser!?

Is there anyway in the web.config to specify DateTime.Now/UtcNow to run in my web server's culture by default?  I only want client cultures to be applied when I write code specifically for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jon mentioned, DateTime.UtcNow (or any DateTime) does not have a culture -- it's essentially a UInt64 representation of a date, so it's just a number. When it's converted to a string for display (including by your debugger), that's when a culture would apply.

To address the question of how the browser culture settings could affect the culture settings on the server, is it possible that you have `culture` set to `auto` in the `globalization` section of your web.config or in a page directive (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bz9tc508(v=vs.100).aspx)?

> To have ASP.NET set the UI culture and culture to the first language that is specified in the current browser settings, set UICulture and Culture to auto.

Comment: Yes! You're right, I changed the web.config from auto to en-US and all is well now on my site.  Thank you!  This was a great fix.

Answer (score 5):

`DateTime.Now` and `DateTime.UtcNow` don't have *any* culture at all. It's only when you format one as a string that it will use a culture... and which culture is used will depend on how you format it. To be clear in your code, just specify the culture explicitly, e.g.

```
string text = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

However, `DateTime.Now` *will* use the system-local time zone (i.e. the one on the server). That's orthogonal to the culture used for formatting.

Comment: Thank you Jon for your reply!  However, I don't think this is quite true.  DateTime.UtcNow shows 19/8/2014 if my browser has en-GB specified, even though the web server the code is running on is en-US, so it should be 8/19/2014.  It seems as though DateTime.Now/UtcNow in fact has the brower's client culture applied, rather than the server's system it is running on.  This can't be right... just stepping through in debug on the date object.

Comment: @user2378631: No, you're mistaking `DateTime.UtcNow` for "the text I get when I convert `DateTime.UtcNow` to a string". Those are different things. The `DateTime` value itself doesn't have a culture, and isn't text.

Comment: This is just stepping through the code in debug on the date object.

Comment: @user2378631: So that's the debugger converting the value to a string. It's not inherent in the DateTime value itself.

Comment: Ok, just seems strange that a client setting would impact server code by default.  All of the server side DateTime object properties in debug reflect the browser's client culture en-GB (19/8/2014), even though the web server is running en-US (8/19/2014).  CultureInfo.CurrentCulture is also showing client culture of en-GB.

Not what I was expecting... but I appreciate your help!